# Handling app widget when app gets killed

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I have an application and a corresponding widget for it. Whenever I kill my application by removing it from background processes and then I use my widget, a pop up telling it has crashed comes. 
Instead I want, if the app is killed, widget should run with the previous data it has.
How should I handle this? Can't figure out..My logcat does not show anything about this crash. Please guide..

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: @CommonsWare When it crashes, my logcat does not show anything.

Comment: Then how have you determined that it "crashed"?

Comment: @CommonsWare On my phone, a dialog box pops..

Comment: @CommonsWare Now I am getting messages. I just restarted eclipse and its getting now. So it is a null pointer exception. Once the app is killed, all the buttons/clicks in widget gives me null pointer exception..

Comment: Then you need to use the stack trace, find the lines in your source code that are raising the exception, and determine what is `null`. Then, you can determine what assumptions you are making. For example, perhaps you are assuming that static data members live forever (hint: they do not).

Comment: @CommonsWare It says unable to start receiver (my broadcast receiver). How should I handle it. I have put my parts in try catch but still its not handled. Also, if static members does not live forever, then what should I declare vars as all my vars are static. external scope instead of static??

Comment: This is what happens if you kill an app out from behind an appwidget. The widget won't run "with the data it has" because you've killed it.